# GDB Debugging protections

Tags: gdb

I am trying to reverse engineer a cydia app (binary) and using GDB with IDA Pro.

There seems to be some debugging protection because `main()` is not in the bt stack, and I cannot access any of the functions, class-dump-z and IDA Pro both show the functions clearly.

The last two entries in the BT Stack are:

```
_mh_execute_header<br>
_mh_execute_header<br>
```

This is where `main()` should be.

Has anyone seen these before?

From what I have read `ptrace()` wouldn't let you attach the process but this will let me. I tried to get around `sysctl()` but I don't think this method has been used either.

Does anyone know what else it could be?

Also I do not have the source files.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is exceedingly unclear. What exactly are you asking?

> main() is not in the bt stack,

That's quite common for fully-stripped executables. If you run `nm a.out | grep main` and don't see `main`, then `main` *can't* show up in any stack traces.

That alone does not necessarily prove that the application is using any anti-debugging techniques.

Comment: `That's quite common for fully-stripped executables` Can you still access the functions? Everytime I try to break at a function it never stops or gets recognized and also if I use hex address it still doesn't break at that address for some reason.

Comment: `break sysctl if $r1==4 && *(int *)$r0==1 && *(int *)($r0+4)==14 && *(int *)($r0+8)==1`  
  
after breaking at that point i get  
  
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted<br>0x3b17a350 in __pthread_kill()<

Comment: nm results in `nm: for architecture cputype (12) cpusubtype(9) object: Bridge malformed object (unknown load command 4)`